# webpage sending incomplete data to nodejs backend

Tags: html, node.js, express

Simple form on a webpage (single input field). When submitted, chrome dev tools show `bkmk` key with no data, and express shows that req.body contains `{bkmk: ""}`.

I'm assuming that express is doing everything it should because it has the key. Of course, I need the value.

app.js is boilerplate express 4.16 so no need for bodyparser.

Here's the html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Express</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/skeleton.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed|Roboto+Slab:700" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="enter">
                <form action="/" method="post">
                    <input class="twelve columns form-control" id="entry" type="text" placeholder="pste yr bkmk" name="bkmk">
                    <button type="submit"></button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="row" id="show"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

express router

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

What am I missing that isn't sending the value?

Comment: It works for me. I can send my name and in console see `{ bkmk: 'Dan' }`. Are all of your dependencies up-to-date?

Comment: @DanielD I'd hope so, this script is like 36 hrs old. However, i just noticed that when i submit the form, the webpage spins "waiting for 127.0.0.1" ...Network tab shows the ip as "(pending)", Network > Doc > Timing shows "Stalled". I have no Inspector breakpoints. It's a different question but how can I see what it's waiting for?

Comment: Hmm I'm not too sure on that one. I'm no node expert, but I noticed you aren't using the `body-parser` dependency (https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser). When I comment these out in my local environment, I get undefined returned. Might be worth trying out quick.

Comment: @DanielD as said in the op, express 4.16 doesn't require bodyparser.