# HTML AJAX sending empty object to the backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

This is a node/express/pug project. The front end renders fine but using vanilla ajax sends an empty object.

Basically, it's a single input field with an event listener. When the field submits (changes), it takes the field data, sends it to express. The express router does nothing at this point except pull the sent data (req.body) and send it back in json form.

pug template

```
block content
  div.container
    div#enter.row
      input#entry.twelve.columns.form-control(type='text', placeholder='pste yr bkmk' name='bkmk')
    hr
    div#show.row
```

rendered html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="enter">
        <input class="twelve columns form-control" id="entry" type="text" placeholder="pste yr bkmk" name="bkmk">
        <button type="submit"></button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row" id="show"></div>
</div>
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

JS

```
const ENTRY = document.getElementById("entry")
const SHOW = document.querySelector("div#show")

ENTRY.addEventListener("change", function () {
    addbkmk(this.value);
})

function addbkmk(incoming) {
    let XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log(`incoming: ${incoming}`);             // COMMENT ONE
    XHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            ENTRY.value = ''
            let htmlP = document.createElement('p'); 
            htmlP.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.responseText));
            SHOW.appendChild(htmlP);
        }
    };
    XHR.open("POST", "/", true);
    XHR.send({"incoming": incoming});
    console.log(SHOW.children.length);
}
```

express router.post

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(`req.body: ${req.body}`);               // COMMENT TWO
  res.status(200).json(req.body);
});
```

`COMMENT ONE` in the above source shows the inputted text. `COMMENT TWO` shows an empty object.

What's missing? Why isn't it sending the data

Comment: What chrome-console network tab shows when you send request?

Comment: *serializing eg `XHR.send(JSON.stringify({"incoming": incoming}));`

Comment: @generalhenry it was originally just `XHR.send(incoming)`, and the field entry is plain text. That wasn't working either. does even that need the stringify? [edit] doesn't matter. . . i left it as an object and did what you said, req.body in the back end is still `{}`

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski "Request Payload" shows the outgoing object as `stringify`ed. if it's just `XHR.send(incoming)` it shows the data entered to the field.

Comment: Ok - so if outgoing request have proper JSON data - so the problem is in backend

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski alright, fair enough. Where tho? The right route is taking it, but it's not in the request body. This is actually a workaround based on my earlier post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292783/webpage-sending-incomplete-data-to-nodejs-backend where the express router was the key (input field name) but not the value of the data sent from the form. I did it like this to go around the form. BTW, it's express 4.16 so it doesn't need the `bodyparser` module.

Comment: in router.post try `res.pipe(process.stdout)` if you are sending an http post body it will be logged.  Most likely you're not extracting the post body from the request, which is a stream.

Comment: I'm not expert of express sorry.

Comment: Use the network inspector in Firefox or Chrome for debugging HTTP requests.

Comment: @generalhenry I added re**q**.pipe(process.stdout) ^_^ and it shows the object that I need `{"link":"asdfads"}` which means it actually is making it across to router.post. So where's it hiding?

Comment: `app.use(express.json())`  will wait for the data from the request, and then parse it and add it to reeq.body.   Though on the request side you need to set the content-type header to "application/json"    see https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json

Comment: @generalhenry Thanks for your help thruout all of this! `app.use(express.json());` is already line 17 in app.js. I changed to `XHR.send(link)` so the incoming data would be sent as encoded. `<input formenctype='application/json'...` doesn't work. But if wrapped in a `<form enctype='application/json'...` it returns the json object, but refreshes in the process even tho it's not a render (`res.status(200).json(req.body)`). The input doesn't HAVE to be in a form for AJAX does it?